# Python __repr__ and None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, repr

I'm quite new to Python and currently I need to have a `__repr__` for a SqlAlchemy class.
I have an integer column that can accept `Null` value and SqlAlchemy converts it to `None`.
For example:

```
class Stats(Base):
   __tablename__ = "stats"
   description = Column(String(2000))
   mystat = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
```

What is the correct way to represent the "mystat" field in the `__repr__` function when SqlAlchemy returns `None`?

Comment: The __repr__() just returns a string representation of the python object. I'm not sure that there is a "correct" way to implement it.

Comment: You do understand that in your code example you are creating class attributes, not instance attributes, right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Now that I searched online I know, thank you. That's why I wrote that I'm new to Python :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `__repr__` should return a string that describes the object. If possible, it should be a valid Python expression that evaluates to an equal object. This is true for built-in types like `int` or `str`:

```
>>> x = 'foo'
>>> eval(repr(x)) == x
True
```

If that's not possible, it should be a `'<...>'` string uniquely describing the object. The default `__repr__` is an example of this:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
        pass
>>>
>>> repr(Foo())
'<__main__.Foo object at 0x02A74E50>'
```

It uses the object's address in memory to uniquely identify it. Of course address doesn't tell us much about the object so it's useful to override `__repr__` and return a string describing the object's state.

The object's state is defined by other objects it contains so it makes sense to include their `repr` in yours. This is exactly what `list` or `dict` do:

```
>>> repr(['bar', Foo()])
"['bar', <__main__.Foo object at 0x02A74710>]"
```

In your case, the state is in your `Column` properties so you want to use their `repr`. You can use the `%r` formatting for this, it inserts a `repr()` of the argument:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Stats: description=%r, mystat=%r>' % (self.description, self.mystat)
```

An equivalent using the new formatting:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Stats: description={0.description!r}, mystat={0.mystat!r}>'.format(self)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I've missed the angle brackets (i.e. `< ... >`) convention for `repr`, if we cannot return "code which creates the object back". Also note that `str` falls back to `repr`.

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to find a generic `__repr__` method that could be used on any SQLAlchemy object and only found this page. So, I decided to write my own and here's what I've done:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

if __debug__:
    # monkey-patch in useful repr() for all objects, but only in dev
    def tablerepr(self):
        return "<{}({})>".format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            ', '.join(
                ["{}={}".format(k, repr(self.__dict__[k]))
                    for k in sorted(self.__dict__.keys())
                    if k[0] != '_']
            )
        )
    Base.__repr__ = tablerepr
```

This extends the `Base` class to print out the contents of the particular instance.  So, now every object I create that extends the `Base` will have a `__repr__` method that prints more than just the class name and the instance hash.

**EDIT:** I added an `if __debug__` as this change may cause a leak of information you may not want leaked in a production environment.  I also added a `sorted` so the display will be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the [generic_repr](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#sqlalchemy_utils.models.generic_repr) decorator of sqlalchemy-utils providing a community based solution that suit your needs?

It leaves it as None.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  All the other answers unfortunately pre-date this solution, but this is what people should be using now.  However, it might be beneficial to wrap that decorator in something that checks for a dev environment to prevent leaking of data in production.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `repr(mystat)` is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

'Null' if mystat is None else mystat

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer showing how to override `Base.__repr__` was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  Here it is re-written with f-strings for Python 3.7+ and overriding the flask-sqlalchemy `db.Model`.

```
def override_default_repr(self):
    class_name = self.__class__.__name__
    attribs = ", ".join(
        [
            f"{k}={self.__dict__[k]!r}"
            for k in sorted(self.__dict__.keys())
            if k[0] != "_"
        ]
    )
    return f"<{class_name}({attribs})>"

db.Model.__repr__ = override_default_repr
```