# SQlAlchemy: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship error message

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, relationship, sqlacodegen

I've recently used [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen)

When I try and run against the generated code it get this  message that I've been unable to fix:

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on 
>   relationship Workgrp.usrmst - there are multiple foreign key paths
>   linking the tables. Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a
>   list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign
>   key reference to the parent table.

I'm wondering if someone can shed some light:

Here is the generated code for the relevant tables causing the issue:

```
class Workgrp(Owner):
    __tablename__ = 'workgrp'

    workgrp_id = Column(ForeignKey('owner.owner_id'), primary_key=True)
    workgrp_prntid = Column(Numeric(scale=0, asdecimal=False))
    workgrp_name = Column(String(256))
    workgrp_desc = Column(String(4000))
    workgrp_owner = Column(ForeignKey('usrmst.usrmst_id'))
    workgrp_lstchgtm = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    workgrp_externid = Column(String(20))
    workgrp_profile = Column(Text)
    workgrp_usrmodtm = Column(DateTime)

    usrmst = relationship('Usrmst')


class Usrmst(Owner):
    __tablename__ = 'usrmst'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('usrmst_ak1', 'usrmst_domain', 'usrmst_name'),
    )

    usrmst_id = Column(ForeignKey('owner.owner_id'), primary_key=True)
    usrmst_domain = Column(String(256))
    usrmst_name = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    usrmst_fullname = Column(String(1024))
    usrmst_desc = Column(String(4000))
    usrmst_phoneno = Column(String(40))
    usrmst_pagerno = Column(String(40))
    usrmst_email = Column(String(1024))
    usrmst_emailtype = Column(Numeric(scale=0, asdecimal=False))
    secmst_id = Column(ForeignKey('secmst.secmst_id'))
    lngmst_id = Column(ForeignKey('lngmst.lngmst_id'))
    usrmst_password = Column(String(1024))
    usrmst_externid = Column(String(20))
    usrmst_suser = Column(String(1))
    usrmst_lstchgtm = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    usrmst_orapassword = Column(String(144))
    usrmst_wingroup = Column(String(1))
    usrmst_tmpacct = Column(String(1))
    usrmst_profile = Column(Text)
    usrmst_usrmodtm = Column(DateTime)
    usrmst_principal = Column(String(256))
    usrmst_keytab = Column(String(4000))

    lngmst = relationship('Lngmst')
    secmst = relationship('Secmst')
```

I've looked at the SQLAlchemy docs, and tried things with

- [foreign_keys](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys)
- [primaryjoin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#relationship-custom-foreign)

But ended up with messages like:

- 'Table' object has no attribute 'usrmst_id'
- AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'workgrp_owner'

Here are some screenshots relevant raw Tables in [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/), the Eclipse based SQL Explorer type plugin:

[image: USRMST]
[image: WRKGRP]

I don't think it should make much difference but I'm developing on:

- Windows Server 2012 RC2
- using Oracle 11g
- With Python 3.6.4
- sqlacodegen 1.1.6

There is a snippet I've added after the generated code, with the relevant imports..

```
engine = create_engine("oracle://<dbuser>:<dbpwd>@<host>:<port>/<db>")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
firstjm = session.query(Jobmst).first()
print(firstjm)
```

Other annoying things about the sqlacodegen generated code:

- Didn't generate string implementations, of [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), so printing out a table didn't generically list, table name, followed by key, value pair list for columns and their values.
- Purports to be PEP compliant code, lines often blew the character limit, and so you'd have to go and reformat long comparison strings 'x x' into 'x' ' x' etc ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down the syntactic sugar doing a Google advanced search on the exact term:

- "Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship"
- within the domain : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/
- This yielded this:
  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths
- From that, this seemed to fit the bill:

---

```
usrmst = relationship('Usrmst', foreign_keys=[workgrp_owner])
```

I also overrode the default implementation of `__repr__` for the Base class defined by:

`Base = declarative_base()`

to this:

```
import json
def tablerepr(self):
    return "<{}: ({})>".format(self.__table__,
                             json.dumps(
                                dict(
                                    list(
                                        self.__dict__.items()
                                        )[1:]
                                 ), default=str)
                             )
Base.__repr__ = tablerepr
```

Useful links I found when getting to grips with the objects SQLAlchemy spits out:

- [Alternative `__repr__` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15929677/495157)
- [Python dir() to reflect attributes of an object in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)
- [Dict View Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict-views)
- [Convert dict to string and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547274/convert-a-python-dict-to-a-string-and-back)
- [Datetime not serializable issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

So I end up adding the tablerepr method to my main generated code..

Then in a separate python script I import the generated code with my tweaks, and have code like this:

```
engine = create_engine("oracle://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db>")
inspector = inspect(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
print(session.query(Jobmst).first())
```

Jobmst is a class representing a table I've imported. This represents kind of content that print then generates, with the customer data replaced by .... The table name, then a tuple containing each column name and it's data as key/value pairs:

```
<jobmst: ({"jobmst_id": 1590.0, "jobmst_alias": "1590", "jobmst_owner": 67.0, "jobmst_type": 1.0, "jobmst_dirty": "0", "jobmst_desc": null, "jobmst_vars": null, "jobmst_prntid": 1589.0, "jobmst_crttm": "2001-06-18 10:38:19", "jobmst_active": "N", "jobmst_usrmodtm": "2001-06-29 20:27:06", "jobdtl_id": 1591.0, "evntmst_id": null, "bizunit_id": null, "jobmst_lstchgtm": "2001-06-29 20:27:06", "jobmst_evntoffset": null, "jobmst_desc_type": null, "jobmst_runbook": null, "jobmst_name": "....", "jobmst_runbook_type": null, "jobcls_id": 32.0, "jobmst_mode": null, "jobmst_prntname": "...."})>
```